# Story about Antarctic jungle with giant bugs and exploration team

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading about a story on Wikipedia while looking at various old science-fiction stories when I came across one about an exploration team finding a sort of oasis in Antarctica in which they encountered giant bugs, if I remember correctly giant tardigrade in particular. It's been on my mind recently and i haven't been able to find it for the life of me. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Was the Wikipedia page in English? Also, do you remember if it was a short story or novel?

Comment: This was most famously done by Edgar Rice Burroughs in The Land That Time Forgot and if this is not the story you're looking for, it was certainly the inspriation.  I don't remember tardigrades, but there are dinosaurs

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheLandThatTimeForgot

I looked through the Lost World and Mysterious Antarctic tropes and didn't find a better fit but perhaps that can guide your search.

Comment: @Jenayah It was in english, and I believe it was a short story. I don't believe it was long enough to be classified as a Novel.

Comment: @NullWaltz It was not the Land that Time forgot, I can confirm that. It was definitely in antarctica.

Comment: As always [truth is stranger than fiction](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/jan/18/antarctica-tardigrades-crustaceans-mercer-subglacial-lake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bathybia by Douglas Mawson

I found it myself, sorry!
Turns out it was on a spec evo forum rather than wikipedia!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds similar to "The Beetle Horde" by Victor Rousseau. It is in *Astounding Stories #1* from January 1930. (It concluded in the February 1930  Issue.) So it's a longish short story. It is available on Project Gutenberg [Link to the first part on Project Gutenberg.](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/41481/41481-h/41481-h.htm#The_Beetle_Horde)

Reasons why it sounds similar. A team was exploring the south pole when they discovered a localized warm region. Exploring that they found a bunch of giant beetles. (I don't recall a tardigrade). The story goes on with a "mad" scientist intending to release the horde of giant beetles into the outside world.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's it. I looked for a Wikipedia page on it and there wasn't one, so it couldn't have been the one i'm thinking of. Thanks however!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have misremembered the article and it is about a film not a short story? I ask because Wikipedia has an article on the film [The Land Unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Unknown) that matches your description in some respects.

The Wikipedia article doesn't mention giant insects or *tardigrades*, but does mention a *tarsier*.

Comment: I don't think that was the one I am thinking of, I specifically remember it having something to do with giant bugs. Thanks however!